# How can I encrypt my config.raw file to avoid any kind of attack?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, app-config

I'm working on an android project which communicate with the server via a Webservice (WS).
All Urls to access to my server was declared in a config.raw file.

*To prevent any kind of attack only the webservice has permission  to access to the server.*

I have to upload a file to the server via the webservice (WS). So I encoded it in order to send and save it in the Sql database as a varbinary. But the WS can't receive the stream because of his size.
So I decide to upload it without passing through the webservice but the url to access to the server are in the config.raw file.

***I know that just with the apk file, it's possible to recover the project.***

> My question : Is there any way to encrypt this file in order to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some algorithms of Bouncy Castle are shipped with Android, but I recommend to use Spoongy Castle for this. Use symmetric encryption/decryption (e.g. AES)